# Why is that in n dimensions, we can't represent lower dimensional entities with a single linear equation in cartesian coordinates?

Tags: linear-algebra

In one dimension, we can represent a point as the solution set of a single algebraic equation.

In two dimensions, we can represent a line through a single equation, and points as the common solution set of certain lines.

In three dimensions, we can represent plane as a single equaiton, lines as common solutions of planes, and points as intersection of three planes.

It seems so in n dimensions, we can not represent an n-2 dimensional object (and even anything lower than that) with a single equation. **Why is that?**

---

[Mildly related](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/970775/why-cant-we-eliminate-the-parameter-of-straight-lines-in-higher-dimensions)

Comment: Before attempting to answer this we'd need to know why you think we can't?

Comment: Clueless to be honest @ancientmathematicianIntuitively,

Comment: You must  have some reason for asserting such an unlikely thing.

Comment: I think you didn't understand ancientmathematician comment. We **can** represent an $n-1$ dimensional objects with a single equation.

Comment: So, could you explain represent how to write a line in three dimensions with only a single equation?

Comment: For $n = 3$, $n - 1 = 2$. A line is not a 2-dimensional object.

Comment: ah oops I see @pastebee

Comment: It depends on what you mean by an "equation" and "entity." Your tag is "linear algebra", do you mean "linear equation" and "linear subspaces" (for "entities")?

Comment: In linear algebra classes one typically learns the [Rank-nullity theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rank%E2%80%93nullity_theorem), which answers your quesion...

Answer (score 1):

A single equation $$|x+3|+|5-y|+|z-1|=0$$ represents a $0$-dimensional point $(-3, 5, 1)$ in $\mathbb R^3.$

Comment: $n$ will be at least four.

Comment: @BobDobbs How does it matter? The solution of my equation is three dimensions 'smaller' than the space in which I define it. What is so special in $n$ being _'at least four'_ which can't be handled the same way?

Comment: Oh. Sorry. I misunderstood the question first. Then somehow I thought it is about $n\geq4$. @CiaPan